# Capture `{cli}` output for reporting

Tags: r, logging

I would like to capture the dynamic output produced by `{cli}` to use in error reporting/logging.

Here's an example:

```
my_function <- function(val, return_message = TRUE) {
  
  if(val == 'a'){
    if (return_message) cli::cli_alert("your value {val} = a!")
  } else {
    if (return_message) cli::cli_alert("your value {val} is not equal to a!")
  }
  
  if (return_message) cli::cli_h2("processing now complete")
  
  return(val)
  
}
```

Using `my_function`, it returns `val` and also prints a message that is dynamic, based on the input value:

```
→ your value x is not equal to a!

── processing now complete ──

[1] "x"
```

Is there any way to capture the dynamic output from `{cli}` functions, ideally by appending to a list or a similar method?

Ideal output would be something like this:

```
my_data <- list(val = "x", message = c("your value x is not equal to a!", "processing now complete"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `cli_X()` returns the text, but you could imagine a wrapper that might do what you want.  Consider this as a start:

```r
cli_wrapper <- function(str, type="alert", return_str = TRUE, return_message=TRUE, ...){
  str <- with(list(...), glue::glue(str))
  if(return_message){
    cmd <- glue::glue('cli::cli_{type}("{str}")')
    eval(parse(text=cmd))
  }
  if(return_str){
    invisible(str)  
  }
}
```

In the function above, `return_message` indicates whether the `cli_X()` function should be run and the `return_str` indicates whether the string should be returned (invisibly).  You could then rewrite your function with the `cli_wrapper()` function:

```r
my_function <- function(val, return_message = TRUE) {
  message <- NULL  
  if(val == 'a'){
    message <- c(message, cli_wrapper("your value {val} = a!", type="alert", val = val, return_message = return_messasge))
  }else{
    message <- c(message, cli_wrapper("your value {val} is not equal to a!", type="alert", val = val, return_message = return_messasge))
  }
  message <- c(message, cli_wrapper("processing now complete", type="h2", return_message = return_messasge))
  ret <- list(val=val, message = message)
  invisible(ret)
}
```

Running the function a couple of different ways would give the following output:

```r
my_data <- my_function(val="x", return_message=TRUE)
# → your value x is not equal to a!
#   
#   ── processing now complete ──
# 

my_data
# $val
# [1] "x"
# 
# $message
# [1] "your value x is not equal to a!" "processing now complete"        
# 

my_data <- my_function(val="x", return_message=FALSE)

my_data
# $val
# [1] "x"
# 
# $message
# [1] "your value x is not equal to a!" "processing now complete"
```

Comment: Thanks @DaveArmstrong! This is great. There's some weirdness around `cli` vs. `glue` (i.e., you can use `{.fn arrange}` in `cli` but not `glue`, but this will definitely get me where I need to go. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

{cli} provides a utility function [`cli_fmt()`](https://cli.r-lib.org/reference/cli_fmt.html) which gives a much easier interface for this behaviour.

```r
# Function to test `cli_fmt()`
noisy_identity <- function(x) {
  
  cli::cli_h1("Noisily returning {.val {x}}")
  
  cli::cli_bullets(c(
    "*" = "Here",
    "*" = "are",
    "*" = "some",
    "*" = "bulllets!"
  ))
  
  x  
  
}

# This just returns `"hi"` and prints a bunch of text
noisy_identity("hi")
#> 
#> ── Noisily returning "hi" ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> • Here
#> • are
#> • some
#> • bulllets!
#> [1] "hi"

# Wrapping in `cli_fmt()` means only the message is returned
cli::cli_fmt(noisy_identity("hi"))
#> [1] ""                                                                                  
#> [2] "── Noisily returning \"hi\" ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────"
#> [3] "• Here"                                                                            
#> [4] "• are"                                                                             
#> [5] "• some"                                                                            
#> [6] "• bulllets!"

# We can use this to define a function that modifies other functions so that 
# they return both output value *and* messages produced like so:
capture_cli_messages <- function(fun) {
  function(..., .quiet = TRUE) {
    
    output <- list(result = NULL, messages = NULL)
    
    output$messages <- cli::cli_fmt({
      output$result <- fun(...)
    })
    
    if (!.quiet) cat(output$messages, sep = "\n")
    
    output
    
  }
}

# `capture_cli_messages()` modifies the behaviour of `noisy_identity()`
noisy_identity2 <- capture_cli_messages(noisy_identity)
noisy_identity2("hi")
#> $result
#> [1] "hi"
#> 
#> $messages
#> [1] ""                                                                                  
#> [2] "── Noisily returning \"hi\" ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────"
#> [3] "• Here"                                                                            
#> [4] "• are"                                                                             
#> [5] "• some"                                                                            
#> [6] "• bulllets!"

# The .quiet argument can be used if you still want to print the messages out
noisy_identity2("hi", .quiet = FALSE)
#> 
#> ── Noisily returning "hi" ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> • Here
#> • are
#> • some
#> • bulllets!
#> $result
#> [1] "hi"
#> 
#> $messages
#> [1] ""                                                                                  
#> [2] "── Noisily returning \"hi\" ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────"
#> [3] "• Here"                                                                            
#> [4] "• are"                                                                             
#> [5] "• some"                                                                            
#> [6] "• bulllets!"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>